# Inline images of body is not getting migrated

Tags: migrations, wysiwyg

I am migrating a drupal6 site to drupal7. I am using migration and migrationd2d_ui module for this. Everything is working fine except wysiwyg inline images in body. path is getting migrated for wysiwyg images . But in content [[wysiwyg_imageupload:15:]] is appearing. In drupal 6 wysiwyg with tinymce editor is running. I am using same wysiwyg with tinymce editor in drupal 7. In drupal6 wysiwyg_imageupload module was used for inilne images in body.

How can i migrate these images in drupal 7 ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this question/issue? If so, would you mind writing it up as an extra answer?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Drupal 6 site which you are wishing to migrate was using the [wysiwyg_imageupload](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_imageupload) module for uploading the images to the content region.
If you have a look at the [Repository viewer](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/wysiwyg_imageupload/tree/?h=6.x-2.x) of the module, you'll see that the module defines certain input filters : `Drupal Wiki inline images` to be precise which converts the images saved in format `[[wysiwyg_imageupload:15:]]` into the real path when the page is rendered.

To resolve this, you'll have to implement the prepare function and *actually* change the value of the content and replace the filter formats with src and then run the migration.

Comment: Thanks AjitS ! I am using Drupal-to-Drupal migration UI   for migration . So where i can write prepare fucntion.

Comment: For that you'll have to write a custom module and implement the migration in a custom class. You can extend the classes provided by the migrate_d2d module. Migrate provides a very good [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1006984) which explains it better.